# MVC6 project.json dependencies issue

Tags: visual-studio

So I am migrating a project from MVC5 to MVC6 and I have hit my first issue.
I have modified the dependencies section of the project.json file and now my project won't compile.

It looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-*"
},
```

I decided to use wildcards and now when I try to build my project I get loads of errors stating things like:

> > The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet'

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I faced similar errors when trying to migrate from MVC 5 to MVC 6 and finally gave up and started from scratch.

Comment: :( just seems stupid, all these versions. If they don't play together nicely, then there should be some sort of repository telling you what versions work....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the * for the dependency versions. Many of these packages are versioned at different rates, and each version is currently dependent on a specific version of the runtime.  When using the * you may be getting rc1, rc2, and beta8 packages mixed together. There could easily be significant changes in these packages that break references.  For instance, the Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS package was deprecated and does not have an rc1 or rc2 version.

This product is still in development and there is quite a lot of change.  Although changes are starting to slow as the RTM date approaches.

I would recommend waiting until the official release to begin migrating your projects.  Otherwise, make sure all your packages are targeting the same runtime version, currently "-rc1-final".  Also make sure you have the latest versions of the [Visual Studio tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959).

Also check the [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) for updates.  There is also a lot of useful nuggets to be found in the [community stand-up meetings](https://live.asp.net).